# Receiving data from .net web service in android using SOAP

Tags: android, .net, soap, asmx, ksoap

Good day everyone. Please help me. My android application always go to my CATCH part.

But if i invoke my .net web service, i get right result and here it is:

```
<LoginModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<Status>Accept</Status>
<ErrMessage/>
<ErrNo>1</ErrNo>
<Username>dan</Username>
<Firstname>Dan</Firstname>
<MiddleName>Francisco</MiddleName>
<Lastname>Francisco</Lastname>
<UserID>26d4d0fe-1d39-46c2-bd12-0a1ee4acdc24</UserID>
<UserType>Admin</UserType>
<LastLoginDate>12/6/2014 11:10:58 AM</LastLoginDate>
</LoginModel>
```

here is my code.

```
package com.example.sampulan;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.ksoap2.*;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.*;
import org.ksoap2.transport.*;


public class login extends Activity {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Login";
    private static final String OPERATION = "Login";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:1338/WSTrafficTicketing.asmx";


    Button loginBtn;
    String user, pass,errmess,errno,status;
    EditText uname, password;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.unameET);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passET);
        loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginB);
        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                user = uname.getText().toString();
                pass = password.getText().toString();

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, OPERATION);
            request.addProperty("Username", user);
            request.addProperty("Password", pass);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelop;
            envelop = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelop.dotNet = true;
            envelop.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE trans = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try {
                trans.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelop);
                SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelop.getResponse();
                SoapObject result2 = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(0);
                status = result2.getProperty(0).toString();

                if(status.equals("Accept")){
                Intent i = new Intent("com.example.sampulan.MENU");
                startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Intent i = new Intent("com.example.sampulan.LOGIN");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please help me fix this :( What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do.

Comment: H4SN - i want to check my status if it is "Accept", and if it is true then i want to go to my MENU Activity

Comment: But it always go on my CATCH part. Please help me

Comment: what exception you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

you cant do network operations on UI thread
try this

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.unameET);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passET);
        loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginB);
        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            user = uname.getText().toString();
            pass = password.getText().toString();

            new Thread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, OPERATION);
                    request.addProperty("Username", user);
                    request.addProperty("Password", pass);
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelop;
                    envelop = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelop.dotNet = true;
                    envelop.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    HttpTransportSE trans = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    try {
                        trans.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelop);
                        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelop.getResponse();
                        SoapObject result2 = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(0);
                        status = result2.getProperty(0).toString();

                        if(status.equals("Accept")){
                            Intent i = new Intent("com.example.sampulan.MENU");
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    startActivity(i);

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception

                        Intent i = new Intent("com.example.sampulan.LOGIN");
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                startActivity(i);

                            }
                        });




                    }

                }


            }).start();





        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I got same result. Even if i login registered user.

Comment: I run it using LogCat and give me a message of "android.os.networkonmainthreadexception"